# How do I write a regex that eliminates the space between a number and a colon?

Tags: ruby, regex, space

I want to replace a space between one or two numbers and a colon followed by a space, a number, or the end of the line. If I have a string like,

```
line = "   0 : 28 : 37.02"
```

the result should be:

```
"   0: 28: 37.02"
```

I tried as below:

```
line.gsub!(/(\A|[ \u00A0|\r|\n|\v|\f])(\d?\d)[ \u00A0|\r|\n|\v|\f]:(\d|[ \u00A0|\r|\n|\v|\f]|\z)/, '\2:\3')
# => "  0: 28 : 37.02"
```

It seems to match the first `":"`, but the second `":"` is not matched.  I can't figure out why.

Comment: At least for testing, use `gsub` instead of `gsub!`. The latter modifies `line`, so if you for execute it, then change your code and run it again, without remembering to reinitialize `line`, you'll get a dog's breakfast that will leave you thoroughly puzzled about what is going on. I can't see why you'd want to use the bang version anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding the third digit can be done with a negative lookback, but since the other one or two digits are of variable length, you cannot use positive lookback for that part.

```
line.gsub(/(?<!\d)(\d{1,2}) (?=:[ \d\$])/, '\1')
# => "   0: 28: 37.02"
```

Comment: Very nice, but it needs a tweak. If `line = "0 :"`, `line` is returned (rather than `"0:"`). I think you need to write the lookahead as `(?=:(?:[ \d]|$))`. Anchors in character classes seem to be disregarded. I think it's because they are not characters. While your at it you might change the space before the lookahead to `[[:space:]]` or `\p{Space}`, so that `"0\u00A0:"` becomes `"0:"`. (See OP's code re whitespace.)

Comment: You could also use `\K` (disregard all matches so far) instead of the capture group and backreference: `"   0 : 28\u00A0: 37.02".gsub(/(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\K[[:space:
]](?=:(?:[ \d]|\z))/, '') #=> "   0: 28: 37.02"`.

Comment: It occurred to me that one can use a negative, rather than positive, lookahead, as I did in my updated answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I forgot to escape. Thanks.

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the problem I mentioned with `line = "0 :"`

Answer (score 3):

**The problem**

I'll define your regex with comments (in free-spacing mode) to show what it is doing.

```
r =
/
(                        # begin capture group 1
  \A                     # match beginning of string (or does it?)
  |                      # or
  [ \u00A0|\r|\n|\v|\f]  # match one of the characters in the string " \u00A0|\r\n\v\f"
)                        # end capture group 1
(\d?\d)                  # match one or two digits in capture group 2   
[ \u00A0|\r|\n|\v|\f]    # match one of the characters in the string " \u00A0|\r\n\v\f"
:                        # match ":"
(                        # begin capture group 3
  \d                     # match a digit
  |                      # or
  [ \u00A0|\r|\n|\v|\f]  # match one of the characters in the string " \u00A0|\r\n\v\f"
  |                      # or                              
  \z                     # match the end of the string
)                        # end capture group 3
/x                       # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note that `'|'` is not a special character ("or") within a character class. It's treated as an ordinary character. (Even if `'|'` were treated as "or" within a character class, that would serve no purpose because character classes are used to force any one character within it to be matched.)

Suppose

```
line = "   0 : 28 : 37.02"
```

Then

```
line.gsub(r, '\2:\3')
   #=> "  0: 28 : 37.02"
$1 #=> " "
$2 #=> "0"
$3 #=> " "
```

In capture group 1 the beginning of the line (`\A`) is not matched because it is not a character and only characters are not matched (though I don't know why that does not raise an exception). The special character for "or" (`'|'`) causes the regex engine to attempt to match one character of the string `" \u00A0|\r\n\v\f"`. It therefore would match one of the three spaces at the beginning of the string `line`.

Next capture group 2 captures `"0"`. For it to do that, capture group 1 must have captured the space at index 2 of `line`. Then one more space and a colon are matched, and lastly, capture group 3 takes the space after the colon.

The substring `' 0 : '` is therefore replaced with `'\2:\3' #=> '0: '`, so `gsub` returns `"  0: 28 : 37.02"`. Notice that one space before `'0'` was removed (but should have been retained).

**A solution**

Here's how you can remove the last of one or more Unicode whitespace characters that are preceded by one or two digits (and not more) and are followed by a colon at the end of the string or a colon followed by a whitespace or digit. (Whew!)

```
def trim(str)
  str.gsub(/\d+[[:space:]]+:(?![^[:space:]\d])/) do |s|
    s[/\d+/].size > 2 ? s : s[0,s.size-2] << ':'
  end
end
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more digits followed by one or more whitespace characters, followed by a colon (all these characters are matched), not followed (negative lookahead) by a character other than a unicode whitespace or digit". If there is a match, we check to see how many digits there are at the beginning. If there are more than two the match is returned (no change), else the whitespace character before the colon is removed from the match and the modified match is returned.

```
trim  "   0 : 28 : 37.02"
  #=> "   0: 28: 37.02"  xxx
trim  "   0\v: 28 :37.02"
  #=> "   0: 28:37.02"
trim  "   0\u00A0: 28\n:37.02"
  #=> "   0: 28:37.02"
trim  "   123 : 28 : 37.02"
  #=> "   123 : 28: 37.02"
trim  "   A12 : 28 :37.02"
  #=> "   A12: 28:37.02"
trim  "   0 : 28 :"
  #=> "   0: 28:"
trim  "   0 : 28 :A"
  #=> "   0: 28 :A"
```

If, as in the example, the only characters in the string are digits, whitespaces and colons, the lookbehind is not needed.

You can use Ruby's `\p{}` construct, `\p{Space}`, in place of the POSIX expression `[[:space:]]`. Both match a class of Unicode whitespace characters, including those shown in the examples.

Comment: Thanks, but to the last part of my question -- how do I factor in that I only want to do the matching if the ":" is followed by a space, a number or the end of the line?

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I really need to read questions more carefully. I also missed the requirement that numbers containing more than two digits are not to be matched. I did an edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
"   0 : 28 : 37.02".gsub!(/(\d)(\s)(:)/,'\1\3')
 => "   0: 28: 37.02"
```

Comment: Of the proposed solutions, this is the only one I can read and know immediately what it does.

Comment: How do you apply this answer only if the ":" is followed by a space, a number, or the end of a line?